# Why are deleted answers still visible?

Tags: support

Here is the question I asked at Math.SE: [Problem in arithmetic progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111965/solve-this-problem-in-arithmetic-progressions/111993#111993)

I got an answer from a user called Tapu. I wanted to upvote it to appreciate his correct method because someone already answered my question correctly. But the I get a message saying that post was deleted. My question is, if the post is deleted is it still visible? I don't understand.

Also I just doubt that it's me who asked the question so all the posts will be visible to the person who asks the question. Looking for clarification.

Comment: If you reload the page, is the answer still there? Maybe the answer was deleted after you loaded the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What most likely happened is that the user deleted his own answer in between the time you loaded the page, and the time you tried to vote on it.

No answer by a user called Tapu is currently visible on that question (except to 10k users of that site, I guess).